# Build image for mips AND application (part of same image) for host

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I can successfully build and run a MIPS image on my target device. I use a command such as:

```
bitbake <image-name>
```

I also want to be able to build an executable (and all its dependencies) that is part of the same image, to run on my x86_64 host. Using my image configuration of build above, I can execute a partial build of my image simply by giving the following command:

```
bitbake <name-of-executable>
```

Obviously, without any changes the executable (and all its dependencies) will be a MIPS-build.

What do I have to change to have the executable (and all its dependencies) be built to run on my developer machine, an x86_64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to build a `-native` version of your recipe.

Often, this is possible by adding the following line to your recipe, `example.bb`:

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"
```

That would allow you to call `bitbake example` to still create the package for MIPS, while allowing you to call `bitbake example-native` to create a package / binary to be used within the bitbake environment. (I.e. it's built for `x86_64` in your case).